# Python 3.3.2 - Rounding to a Number Whilst Keeping Decimals

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

I know the question sounds it a bit weird, I can't think of a way to explain it.

Basically, I need to round numbers without cutting off extra zeros and such. For example, my current `format(round(whatever, 3))` will round something like `1.00000024` to `1.0`, when I want it to round to `1.000`. I know the practicality of this is stupid, but I need to do this so as to not confuse people when the numbers they get aren't the same length.

Help, please?

Answer (score 5):

The number of digits displayed after the decimal point isn't a property of the `float` representing the number - it's a property of how you display it. The [`format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) built-in or the [string `format` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) can use a [format spec](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) to control how numbers are displayed:

```
print('{:.3f}'.format(1.0))  # prints 1.000
```

See the links for how to use format specs - there are a lot of options, and they can get kind of confusing.